# auto start app when boot completed android

Tags: java, android, boot

I've been reading a lot on this subject but for some reason I'm unable to make this work.
My application records the location of the user every 5 minutes. When the user reboots the phone I'm unable to auto start the app.
I'm able to check the location of the user every 5 minutes so the alarms are working.

Here is my android manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" ></receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and the AlarmBroadcastReceiver
     public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("LOG","I've been Called");}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/603233 first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

To your `<receiver>` element in the manifest.